# is there any concept like FrameLayout (Android) in java Swing?

Tags: java, android, swing, awt

I am new to java `Swing` framework and have been working with android since many years. So, naturally I am relating Android's layout with java's swing layouts.

I have requirement of something like `FrameLayout` in android.

`FrameLayout` of android works as;

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a single item. You can add multiple children to a FrameLayout, but all children are pegged to the top left of the screen. Children are drawn in a stack, with the most recently added child on top. The size of the frame layout is the size of its largest child (plus padding), visible or not (if the FrameLayout's parent permits).

Is there any layout or any implementation which works in similar way?

I need to implement the following UI. In this; there is a `Container` which holds `JTabbedPane`. I have implemented it partially, I am not able to implement the dark bar behind the tabs.

[image]

any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: `CardLayout` or `BorderLayout` maybe

Comment: `I am not able to implement the dark bar behind the tabs.` - that shouldn't be a problem. Each platform has its own LAF. You shouldn't try to make it look identical on each platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use jdesktoppane instant of FrameLayout
you can get more detail from

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html